# Call function from extension of the generic class / generic class method dispatch

Tags: swift, generics, extension-methods

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

protocol ModuleConfigurator {
    func execute()
}
protocol ModuleProperties { }

class BackupCardProperties { }
extension BackupCardProperties: ModuleProperties { }
class IntroductionProperties { }
extension IntroductionProperties: ModuleProperties { }


class Configurator<T> where T: ModuleProperties {

    // MARK: - Properties

    var properties: T

    // MARK: - Initialization

    init(properties: T) {
        self.properties = properties
    }
}
extension Configurator: ModuleConfigurator {
    func execute() {
        print("Configurator")
    }
}

extension Configurator where T == IntroductionProperties {
    func execute() {
        print("IntroductionProperties")
    }
}

extension Configurator where T == BackupCardProperties {
    func execute() {
        print("BackupCardProperties")
    }
}

var list: [ModuleConfigurator] = [Configurator<BackupCardProperties>(properties: BackupCardProperties()),
                                  Configurator<IntroductionProperties>(properties: IntroductionProperties())]

list.forEach { config in
    config.execute()
}
```

> Configurator
>   Configurator

Is it possible to achieve

> BackupCardProperties
>   IntroductionProperties

**EDIT**

The without protocol

```
protocol ModuleConfigurator {
    func execute()
}
protocol ModuleProperties { }

class BackupCardProperties { }
extension BackupCardProperties: ModuleProperties { }
class IntroductionProperties { }
extension IntroductionProperties: ModuleProperties { }


class Configurator<T> where T: ModuleProperties {

    // MARK: - Properties

    var properties: T

    // MARK: - Initialization

    init(properties: T) {
        self.properties = properties
    }
}
extension Configurator where T == IntroductionProperties {
    func execute() {
        print("IntroductionProperties")
    }
}

extension Configurator where T == BackupCardProperties {
    func execute() {
        print("BackupCardProperties")
    }
}
Configurator<BackupCardProperties>(properties: BackupCardProperties()).execute()
```

Comment: This is a known drawback of implementing the protocol method in its own extension. Some ways to overcome this issue are discussed here https://dzone.com/articles/getting-hurt-with-swift-protocol-extensions-and-de

Comment: @Kamran the same behaviour without protocol

Comment: No, in the `Edit`, your print statement(`print("Configurator")`)  is same in `execute` method otherwise it is calling their respective methods.